# Graphs is not plotting properly in the subplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, subplot

I have I have a **[data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xawyksrrmxcq40/Data_test.txt?dl=0)** which has 3 columns, 1st column is the field for the data, or you can say different index. 2nd column is the x-axis data, and the 3rd column is the y-axis data. Now I have similar data files for different variables like 8 files. I want to plot all the graph in one figure in MATLAB. For my problem, I am showing only one subplot. This subplot data file should plot 5 "line plots" for 5 indexes (1st column). But when I plot it as subplot it shows only 1 plot. here is my code in the below:

```
% open Zdiff Odd Mode data file
fid = fopen('Data_test.txt');
% Read data in from csv file
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

% Extract data from readData
index_Data = readData{1,1}(:,1);
% Identify the unique indices
uni_idx=unique(index_Data);
xData = readData{1,2}(:,1);
yData = readData{1,3}(:,1);


% Plot Data
f = figure;
%Top Title for all the subplots
p = uipanel('Parent',f,'BorderType','none'); 
p.Title = 'Electrical Characteristics'; 
p.TitlePosition = 'centertop'; 
p.FontSize = 14;
p.FontWeight = 'bold';

cla; hold on; grid on, box on;

ax1 = subplot(2,4,1,'Parent',p);
% Loop over the indices to plot the corresponding data
for i=1:length(uni_idx)
   idx=find(index_Data == uni_idx(i));
   plot(xData(idx,1),yData(idx,1))
end
```

The plot results like below:
[image]

When I plot the data as a full figure, the plot is perfect. But as I have lots of data to plot in one figure as subplots, I need to know what is wrong in my subplot code.

**Here is my code for the whole figure of the data without the subplot**

Before plotting code it is same as before:

```
% Plot Data
f1 = figure(1);
cla; hold on; grid on;

% Loop over the indices to plot the corresponding data

for i=1:length(uni_idx)
   idx=find(index_Data == uni_idx(i));
   plot(xData(idx,1),yData(idx,1))
end
```

The resulting figure is below:
[image]

What is wrong with my plotting code in the subplot? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to hold on in each subplot, not before. Only then is the axis selected

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks a lot....such a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your sequence of commands, and what they do:

```
f = figure;
```

Creates an empty figure, there are no axes yet defined here.

```
cla
```

Clears the current axes, since there is no current axes, it creates one.

```
hold on
```

Sets the "hold" property on the current axes

```
grid on, box on
```

Sets some other properties of the current axes

```
ax1 = subplot(2,4,1,'Parent',p);
```

Creates new axes. Because it overlays the previously created axes, those are deleted.

```
plot(xData(idx,1),yData(idx,1))
```

Plots to the current axes (i.e. the one created by `subplot`). These axes don't have the "hold" property set, so subsequent `plot` commands will overwrite the data plotted here.

The solution, as [suggested by Ander in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298178/graphs-is-not-plotting-properly-in-the-subplot-in-matlab#comment91544232_52298178), is to set the "hold" property of the axes created by `subplot`. Replace:

```
cla; hold on; grid on, box on;
ax1 = subplot(2,4,1,'Parent',p);
```

with:

```
ax1 = subplot(2,4,1,'Parent',p);
hold on; grid on, box on;
```

(note that `cla` is not necessary, since you're drawing to a new, empty figure).